# Is it OK for a subsequent TDD test to make an earlier test obsolete

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm new to TDD.

A generic example:

- Step 1. Create a failing test case -> test case 1
- Step 2. Fix the failing test case by editing the code (for loop that populates data)
- Step 3. test case 1 is now green
- Step 4. Create another failing test case -> test case 2 (within the for loop, there is now if statement)
- Step 5. Fix the failing test case again
- Step 6. test case 2 is now green

My test case 1 becomes obsolete, since it only checked if the for loop works. 
It will become red since I would be asserting equals expected data, but since it will not pass the if condition (which in test case 1 i did not properly set), the expected data will not be available.

Please shed some light. I'm sure I'm doing something terribly wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test cases shouldn't need to be aware of how you're going to implement it. For example, you don't test that you have a loop, but you test that the data is populated.

Also test case doesn't need to be write once only, in many cases you'll need  to edit your previous test case as you implement a new aspect of the functionality that invalidated the old test case.

In your particular case here, you can either write your first test case such that it avoids triggering the if condition, and have second test case trigger the if condition occasionally. Or instead of creating a second test case, you can edit the first test case so it tests both the for loop and the if condition.